# Why is my flutter app using so much storage in 'Documents & Data'?

Tags: ios, flutter, local-storage, storage

I am currently perplexed as to why my app is using so much storage, as displayed in iPhone Storage settings.

[image: Screenshot of my app's storage in iPhone settings]

I ran the following method to get an approximation of how much storage im using in my app:

```
Future<void> listFilesInAllDirectories() async {
  final Directory tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
  final Directory appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  final Directory appSupportDir = await getApplicationSupportDirectory();
  final Directory libraryDir = await getLibraryDirectory();

  List<Directory> directories = [tempDir, appDocDir, appSupportDir, libraryDir];

  int grandTotalSize = 0;

  for (var directory in directories) {
    int totalSize = await getDirectorySize(directory);

    if (totalSize > 0) { // Skip over directories that do not contain any files
      grandTotalSize += totalSize;
      print("Directory: ${directory.path}");
      double sizeInMB = totalSize / (1024 * 1024);
      print("Total size of directory: ${sizeInMB.toStringAsFixed(2)} MB");
    }
  }

  double grandTotalSizeInMB = grandTotalSize / (1024 * 1024);
  print("Grand total size: ${grandTotalSizeInMB.toStringAsFixed(2)} MB");
}

Future<int> getDirectorySize(Directory dir) async {
  int size = 0;
  try {
    List<FileSystemEntity> children = dir.listSync();
    for (var child in children) {
      if (child is File) {
        size += await child.length();
      } else if (child is Directory) {
        size += await getDirectorySize(child);
      }
    }
  } catch (e) {
    print("An error occurred: $e");
  }
  return size;
}
```

And this method outputted the following:

```
flutter: Directory: /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/4258E4C7-1B2C-428F-BCB5-782683E12F51/Library/Caches
flutter: Total size of directory: 7.18 MB
flutter: Directory: /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/4258E4C7-1B2C-428F-BCB5-782683E12F51/Documents
flutter: Total size of directory: 146.43 MB
flutter: Directory: /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/4258E4C7-1B2C-428F-BCB5-782683E12F51/Library/Application Support
flutter: Total size of directory: 0.11 MB
flutter: Directory: /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/4258E4C7-1B2C-428F-BCB5-782683E12F51/Library
flutter: Total size of directory: 12.49 MB
flutter: Grand total size: 166.21 MB
```

For Context, in my app I currently am only storing images permanently in the Application Documents Directory. I do use the Temporary Directory however I delete all files I create in this folder after they have been used for their purpose. And before I ran this 'experiment', I cleaned this folder with another dart script.

I would really appreciate if someone has any suspicions of what is going on here and could provide an explanation as to how my app is using so much storage in Documents & Data?

Comment: Is your app built in debug or release mode? If it's debug, then various development services and temporary files may take hundreds of MB of space.

Comment: @BartekPacia its built in debug mode. But I have my app on the app store, and when I run the app, itjust updates the app store version with the version on my local machine.